# C++ design for multiple versions of same interface (enumerations / structures in header files)

Tags: c++, struct, interface, enums

We are interfacing with an externally controlled program with defined headers containing enumerations, and structures.  We want to be able to interface with multiple versions of this program with as little duplication of code as possible.  Each version has the same general enums and structures, but with slight modifications over time.  In the ideal setup we could just conditionally include the different versions of the same header (i.e. if interfacing with version 1 #include "version1\progDefs.h", else #include "version2\progDefs.h"), but don't believe that is possible in C++.

Below is a simple example to illustrate the issue and what we are currently doing.  Thank you for any assistance.

version1\progDefs.h contains

```
enum items
{  
  BOOK_TYPE = 0,
  PAGE_TYPE = 1,
  WORD_TYPE = 2
};
struct packet
{
  int type;
};
```

version2\progDefs.h contains

```
enum items
{  
  VOLUME_TYPE = 0,
  BOOK_TYPE = 1,
  PAGE_TYPE = 2,
  WORD_TYPE = 3
};
struct packet
{
  int type;
  char detail[80];
};
```

We now want to write out the packet structure to the network, being able to pick at runtime which version to use.  Currently we have a base class and then one child class for each version.  They look something like this

baseWriter.h

```
class baseWriter
{
    virtual void sendBookPacket() = 0;
};
```

version1Writer.cpp

```
#include "baseWriter.h"
#include "version1\progDefs.h"

class version1Writer : public baseWriter {};
void version1Writer::sendBookPacket()
{
  struct packet pkt;
  pkt.type = BOOK_TYPE;
  sendNetworkPacket((void*)&pkt, sizeof(pkt));
}
```

version2Writer.cpp

```
#include "baseWriter.h"
#include "version2\progDefs.h"

class version2Writer : public baseWriter {};
void version2Writer::sendBookPacket()
{
  struct packet pkt;
  pkt.type = BOOK_TYPE;
  sendNetworkPacket((void*)&pkt, sizeof(pkt));
}
```

This will work, but as you can see the code is the exact same in both classes.  The only difference is in the values and structure used because of the different version of headers.  In reality the project has many enumerations with hundreds of items, and many structures, none of which we have control over.  They can change at any time, but our code doesn't need to as the new elements are not relevant to the program.  However the changes do effect the values / size of the elements used.  Is there any way to design our code to use these headers without duplicating code? Thank you!

Note: We do not have support for C++11. Thank you for the suggestions.  Many are suggestions coding terms I'm unfamiliar with and will have to test to see if supported by compiler and will try and respond to each individually.

Comment: Can you modify `progDefs.h` contents?

Comment: It is another program's interface.  So while we can physically modify the header files, the values need to be as defined.  I.e. to interface with version 1 we must sent a packet of 4 bytes with value 0.  For version 2 we must send a packet of 84 bytes with value 1 in first 4 bytes.  Thank you for viewing question.

Comment: Conditional inclusion is definitely possible in C++, but you can't pick at runtime. (It's one of C and C++'s controversial features)

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the contents of each `progDefs.h` file into a struct, preferably directly, or if you can't  modify it, like this:

```
struct Version1 {
#include "version1\progDefs.h"
};
```

Then you can make `baseWriter` a template class:

```
template <typename Version>
class baseWriter
{
    using packet = typename Version::packet;
    using items = typename Version::items;

    void sendBookPacket() {
        packet pkt;
        pkt.type = items::BOOK_TYPE;
        sendNetworkPacket((void*)&pkt, sizeof(pkt));
    }
};
```

And then

```
using version1Writer = baseWriter<Version1>;
using version2Writer = baseWriter<Version2>;
```

**Update:**
If C++11 is not available, replace `using X = Y` in the code above to `typedef Y X`. That is, e.g

```
typedef typename Version::packet packet;
```

You can also do everything without these typedefs, they just simplify the code a bit.

Comment: In this case is "using" a new feature of C++11?  I'm only familiar with it in regards to namespaces.  Compiler didn't like this syntax.  Thank you.

Comment: @talisman: yes it is new feature of C++11. If you are using the older compiler, change using with typedef

Comment: @talisman yes, you can use `typedef` as @MantoshKumar said, see my update.

Comment: Thank you! It took a bit for me to get it to compile, as I don't generally use templates nor enums in structures, but this solution did work.  Note: when changed to typedef method had to make items::BOOK_TYPE be Version::BOOK_TYPE.  Not sure if that was an error for C++11 as well, or just a symptom of changing to typedef.  Thank you again - will have to determine if this will make sense for the larger project.  Never mixed templates with inheritance.

Comment: @talisman Glad that it helped. Regarding `items::BOOK_TYPE` vs `Version::BOOK_TYPE` - it's also a feature in C++11 that you can use enum name for scope resolution even for old-style enums. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good candidate for [Visitor Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/cpp/1).  The visitor pattern will allow you to choose which object to instantiate at runtime instead of compile time.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this suggestion?  Which aspect is the visitor, which is the color?  Thank you for the reply

Comment: @talisman: If we use the example in the link, your BaseWriter becomes the Color base class, and your version1Writer and version2Writer become the Red and Blu classes, respectively.

Comment: Then the visitor would be for the sendBookPacket function?  But in the example provided the countVisitor just included the variables for both red and blue.  We could use namespaces to include both versions of headers in the visitor, but can't see how that would save duplication of code as we'd have to instantiate and reference all versions of structures and enumerations.

Comment: You could have the visitor funcitons do the stuff that's different and then call a common function in the base class.

Comment: I apologize, but I can't envision the answer.  As described above the whole function is common.  The issue is it needs to reference a structure type and enumeration value, which has multiple definitions depending on which header you use. If there is a code snippet you can show using above example which handles this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ok.  Separate the packing of the struct and the sending of it into 2 separate functions.  The packing one (this is the different one since it includes different struct defs) will be the "visitor function".  The sending function will be common.  The visitor classes will include the different struct def files and do the packing.  If you happen to have fields that are the same, you will have to duplicate them but this seems like a good thing since it prevents changes to one from affecting the others.  You still get the benefit of a common interface to the entire thing.

Comment: Thank you rost again.  I understand your suggestion now.  And this is actually what I'm doing now with the base and virtual classes.  I was hoping to find a trick to improve on this as all the code is exactly the same.  The entire function - packing, enumerations, and sending are exactly the same code lines between all the versions, so was trying to avoid the extra duplication of code.  The versions once I get them won't change, though new versions will come out later.  Eventually the trick might not work, but the question was to avoid any duplicate lines of code - maybe not possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic.  Feel free to upvote the answer.  Maybe others will find this useful too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to duplicate your code, like you did, if you want to be sure it works. You don't have to duplicate it by hand, you can generate the code automatically to save you the work and many potential bugs.

Comment: We thought of macros to autogenerate the code per child class, but not preferred method.  Thanks for the reply